# VB6 uses VB.NET class - it is slow

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have a VB6 app, which needs to use some functionality from a .NET class.  I have created a .tlb (type library) for the .NET class and the VB6 app calls it.

The problem is that it is slow.  I loop around every record in a database and call functionality in the .TLB for every loop.

My question is: is this approach inherently slow? What is the reason for this?

The code in .NET is duplicated in VB6 (I know this isn't good practice - I didn't do it).  The VB6 code use to use the VB6 class and it was much faster.  This is how I have concluded that using the .NET class is too slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unmanaged to managed code transition can be slow because any data structures you pass must be marshaled.

For example, if you pass a string then the entire string is copied into a new .NET string object on the managed heap.

If you pass a reference to an object, then an RCW (run-time callable wrapper) is generated on the .NET side. (Calling these objects from .NET may then cause marshaling overhead again in the other direction.)

For more details, see the [Interop Marshaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) topic on MSDN.